# Problem with getting a javascript varible into a HTML element

Tags: javascript, html

I have 1 variable witch i would want to get into the `p` element in the code.

```
let firstNumber 
<p>
 
<p>
```

I dont know how to put the variable value into the `p` element.

I tried the way of doing it in just JS but it of course dident work

Comment: _"I tried the way of doing it in just JS"_ - please show this. Use the `<>` button

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code, to include starting with some introductory tutorials in HTML and JavaScript as needed.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to assign the value.

The easiest way to assign a JS variable to an HTML element's content, is to first find the element by a selector e.g. id, class name, or attribute. After you have the element, you can then assign text, classes, attributes, etc. to it.

This is the most basic DOM manipulation.

```js
let firstNumber = 42;

document.getElementById('target').textContent = firstNumber;

/* Alternatives */
// :- document.querySelector('#target').textContent = firstNumber;
// :- window.target.textContent = firstNumber;

/* Not recommended, since the value is just a number */
// :- document.getElementById('target').innerText = firstNumber;
// :- document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = firstNumber;


// When assigning content to a form input field,
// you need to assign the value.
document.getElementById('be-careful').value = firstNumber;
```

```html
<p id="target"><p>

<!-- Form inputs are different: <input>, <textarea>, etc... -->
<input id="be-careful" type="number" />
```

Comment: Where in the code shuld i put the document.getElementById

Comment: @IsakGrönlund somewhere in your JavaScript code that you call via `<script>`.